# $x\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-nx}$ is continuous but not uniform continuous on $(0,+\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Prove that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-nx}$ is continuous but not uniform continuous on $(0,+\infty)$.

Is there any good ways to deal with this kind of functions?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. To prove the continuity we work locally and we use the uniform convergence:

$$ne^{-nx}\le ne^{-n a},\quad\forall x\ge a$$
and the series $\sum_n ne^{-na}$ is convergent because $ne^{-na}=_\infty o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$  hence we have the uniform convergence of the given series on every interval $[a,+\infty),\;a>0$ and since the functions $x\mapsto ne^{-nx}$ are continuous we conclude the desired result.

This series isn't uniformly convergent on $(0,\infty)$ because $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ doesn't exist.

**Edit** We can prove that the series isn't uniformly convergent using:
$$\sup_{x>0}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty ne^{-nx}\ge \sup_{x>0}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} ne^{-nx}=2n^2\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Could you please explain why $lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)$ doesn't exist..?

Comment: I edited my answer and notice that I proved the non uniform convergence since the series $\sum_n f_n(0)$ is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

- $f$ is continuous over $(0,\infty)$

It suffices to prove that this series of functions converges uniformly over $(a,\infty)$ where $a>0$ is arbitrary.

For $x\in (a,\infty)$, $|n\exp(-nx)|\leq n\exp(-na)$

Conclude with Weierstrass M test.

Then let $a \to 0$

- f is not uniformly continous

Without accounting for term-by-term differentiation, $f'(x)=\sum -n^2\exp(-nx)$

The derivative of $f$ is not bounded, hence $f$ is not uniformly continous.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is equivalent to showing the non-uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n y^n$ on $(0,1)$ if we let $y=e^{-x}$. This sum has a closed form expression given by
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ny^n = \frac{1}{(1-y)^2}$$
since it is the derivative of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n = \frac{1}{1-y}$. Okay. Consider a partial sum $S_N(y) = \sum_{n=0}^N ny^n$. We can bound $|S_N(y)| \leq n(n+1)/2$. If we had uniform convergence, then, we should have for a particular $N$ large
$$\left| \frac{1}{(1-y)^2} - S_N(y) \right| < \epsilon$$
independent of $y$. But this is impossible because $|S_N(y)|$ is bounded and hence the expression in parentheses can become arbitrarily large as $y \to 1$.

To show continuity, use the closed form expression already mentioned. Remember to use the substitution $y=e^{-x}$ as needed.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method of showing this is by seeing that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}} \forall x > 0
$$
Now we can differentiate term by term (only for $x>0$) to see that:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty - n e^{-nx} = -1(1-e^{-x})^{-2} (e^{-x}) = \frac{-e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-x})^2} = \frac{-e^{x}}{(e^x-1)^2} \\
\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty n e^{-nx} = \frac{e^{x}}{(e^x-1)^2}
$$
Now you can prove the righthand is continuous for $x > 0$ in an assortment of ways, the easiest of which uses the continuity of $e^x$ and $(\cdot)^2$.

To show it's not uniformly continuous since:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{1/n}}{(e^{1/n}-1)^2}
$$
is non convergent and so the function composed with a cauchy sequence isn't a cauchy sequence, showing that the function isn't uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer,it's very kind of you!

Comment: @user152441 no problem, I was debating on showing with more details that the final limit is divergent, would that be helpful or do you see how it diverges? Also all of these are great answers, but I suggest you check off the one that helped you the most in order to close this question.